# How to properly launch an animation one time when the element on view with React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm pretty new to React and I try to launch a CSS @keyframes animation when my element come to the viewport.

For this I use the Intersection Observer with useOnScreen hook : https://usehooks.com/useOnScreen/

My JSX :

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'

import './landing.scss'

function useOnScreen(options){
    const ref = React.useRef(); 
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
            setVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
        }, options);

        if (ref.current) {
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }

        return () => {
            if (ref.current) {
                observer.unobserve(ref.current);
            }
        }

    }, [ref, options])

    return [ref, visible];
}

const Landing = () => {
    const [ref, visible] = useOnScreen();

    return(
        <>
        <div className="titleBox">
            <h2 style={{ animationDuration: `0.5s`, animationIterationCount: 1, animationName: visible ? "showTopText" : ``, animationDelay: "0.3s", animationTimingFunction: "ease" }}>My text</h2>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

My scss :

```
@keyframes showTopText {
    0% {top: 100%;}
    100% {top: 0;}
}

.titleBox{
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    h2{
        font-size: 56px;
        line-height: 64px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

My main problem is that the animation repeats every time the element comes back to the screen and also my text load at `top: 0%;` and disappear to `top: 100%;` when the animation start.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something on Stack Overflow that allowed me to do what I want.
I use react-in-viewport and made something like this :

```
const TitleSection2 = (props) => {
    const { inViewport, forwardedRef, enterCount } = props;
    if (inViewport && enterCount === 1) {
        return (
            <div ref={forwardedRef} className="titleBoxSection2">
                <div className="line1">
                    <h2 className="visible">First line</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="line2">
                    <h2 className="visible">second line.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div ref={forwardedRef} className="titleBoxSection2">
            <div className="line1">
                <h2 className="notVisible">First line</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="line2">
                <h2 className="notVisible">second line.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const ViewportTitleSection2 = handleViewport(TitleSection2);
```

With a SCSS like this :

```
.titleBoxSection2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 128px;
        
    .line1{
        width: 100%;
        height: 64px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;

        h2.visible{
            font-size: 56px;
            line-height: 64px;
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
            animation: showTopText 0.5s;
            animation-delay: 0.3s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-timing-function: ease;
            top: 100%;
        }

        h2.notVisible{
            font-size: 56px;
            line-height: 64px;
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
        }
    }

    .line2{
        width: 100%;
        height: 64px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;

        h2.visible{
            font-size: 56px;
            line-height: 64px;
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
            animation: showTopText 0.5s;
            animation-delay: 0.8s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-timing-function: ease;
            top: 100%;
        }

        h2.notVisible{
            font-size: 56px;
            line-height: 64px;
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this isn't the best way, but it works fine for me.
Maybe it can help someone else.
Do not hesitate to correct me.